# React - How to pass local variables into child components

Tags: reactjs

I am running React 15.6 so unfortunately, I don't have access to the new `React.creatRef` function.

In any case, here is my component. I have a local variable called `newPass` in the component which I hook up as an `inputRef` into the `FormControl`. As the user types out a password, `newPass` is populated with what is typed.

```
export class ResetForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let newPass;

        return (
            <div>
                <FormGroup>
                    <ControlLabel>New Password</ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        type="password"
                        onChange={() => {
                            if (newPass) {
                                // validate the password
                            }
                        }}
                        inputRef={(ref) => newPass = ref} />
                </FormGroup>
                <SaveButton {...this.props} newPass={newPass} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, I want to send the value of `newPass` into the child component `SaveButton`.

```
export class SaveButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={() => this.props.doTheSave(this.props.newPass.value);}>
                Save
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

However, when testing, I type in my form and click the Save button, I get an error on the `doTheSave` line saying: `Cannot read value of undefined`. The child component does not seem to know what `newPassword` is. Can anyone advise me how do I pass the result of the local variable down into a child component?

Comment: You call your variable `newPass`, but you pass down `newPassword` to the `SaveButton` component. Is that a typo? You should also put the `newPass` as an instance variable as to not create a new variable every render: You might want to [control the input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) instead so you have a string value in state that you can use.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post. It was indeed a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [control the input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and store the new input value in state every time it changes and give that to the `SaveButton` component instead.

**Example**

```js
class ResetForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    newPass: ""
  };

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ newPass: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { newPass } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <FormGroup>
          <ControlLabel>New Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl type="password" value={newPass} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </FormGroup>
        <SaveButton {...this.props} newPass={newPass} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SaveButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={() => this.props.doTheSave(this.props.newPass)}>
        Save
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

newPassword should hold the ref values for newPass like so:

```
export class ResetForm extends React.Component {
render() {
    let newPass;

    return (
        <div>
            <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel>New Password</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                    type="password"
                    onChange={() => {
                        if (newPass) {
                            // validate the password
                        }
                    }}
                    inputRef={(ref) => newPass = ref} />
            </FormGroup>
            <SaveButton {...this.props} newPassword={newPass} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}